# Ember: Show service variable on template dynamically

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have template which shows the service variable.
And when I update the service variable from other controllers, it doesn't update on template.
How can I implement this?

Code Snippets:

```
component JS file

export default A({
  notification_area: Ember.inject.service(),
  notification_number: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('notification_area').get('total');
  }),
});

Template .hbs file

<div>{{notification_number}}</div>

Other controller: Updates service variable 'total'

let total_notification_number =this.get('notification_area').get('total');
this.get('notification_area').set('total', total_notification_number+1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line instead of your computed property

```
notification_number: Ember.computed.oneWay('notification_area.total')
```

Your code is fine but you forgot to tell your computed property that it monitors changes, so you could also do Ember.computed('notification_area.total',, function() ...

Hope it helps

Comment: hi Mirza, does Ember.computed.oneWay('notification_area.total') will monitor service variable? I am trying now

Comment: Yes. It just created a get and it is not intendent to call set on this property. But it will monitor changes. (computed.oneWay only provides an aliased get.) Here is the docs http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_oneWay

Comment: hi Mirza, you are awesome. It works. Thanks for your help